# salt stack: how to get multiple grains on command line remote execution?

Tags: salt-stack, remote-execution

Using `salt` on the command line, how can I get multiple grains from remote systems?

For example, I can get `os` and `osrelease` individually:

```
salt '*' grains.get os
salt '*' grains.get osrelease
```

But I really want to get them both simultaneously, so I don't have to write a parsing script (or something) to first collect all the answers from os, and match them up with the answers from osrelease...

I want something like this, which would get both grains at once:

```
salt '*' grains.get os,osrelease    (this doesn't work)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`grains.item`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.item) instead.

```
salt '*' grains.item os osrelease
```